# Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' (react)

Tags: reactjs, import, module

Trying to import new module from folder components, but I'm getting some errors

my index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    render
} from 'react-dom'
import {
    Provider as ReduxProvider
} from 'react-redux'
import {
    Router,
    Route,
    IndexRoute,
    Link,
    Redirect,
    browserHistory
} from 'react-router'


import  App  from './components'



import {
    routerMiddleware
} from 'react-router-redux'

import {
    IntlProvider,
    addLocaleData
} from 'react-intl'
import en from 'react-intl/locale-data/en'
import zh from 'react-intl/locale-data/zh'
addLocaleData([...en, ...zh])


    import {
        createStore,
        compose,
        applyMiddleware
    } from 'redux'
    import Immutable from 'immutable'
    import {
        combineReducers
    } from 'redux-immutable'
    import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
    render((
        <ReduxProvider >
            <IntlProvider locale={'en'}>
              <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={App}>



                </Route>
              </Router>
            </IntlProvider>
      </ReduxProvider>
    ), document.getElementById('mount'))
```

Folder with components src/components
there my structure

[image]

My App.JS inside folder components

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'

    export default function App({ children }) {
      return (
        <div>
          1
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default App
```

[image]

So I don't understand why it not see the directory with component's, where I' wrong?

Comment: How do you build this code?

Comment: with webpack by command npm start dev

Comment: Can you post your webpack config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import a directory, the file resolver will look for an `index.js` *inside* that directory.

So this import:

```
import  App  from './components'
```

Is looking for a `./components/index.js` file to import.  This will not import `App.js`.

Try this instead:

```
import  App  from './components/App'
```